# How can I associate multiple domain name with one record in Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I am thinking to use AWS `Route53` to balance traffic among multiple domain names. According AWS doc:

`Associating multiple IP addresses with a single record is often used for balancing the load of geographically-distributed web servers. Amazon Route 53 allows you to list multiple IP addresses for an A record and responds to DNS requests with the list of all configured IP addresses.`

it mentions that it can associate multiple IP addresses but how I can associate with multiple domain names? My use case is that I have multiple application load balancers from different AWS accounts. And I'd like to use route53 to route traffic to these ALB endpoints.

I have tried to create a CNAME with multiple domain name on the list but got an error:

```
InvalidChangeBatch 400: RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name rancher.crms.myzeller.dev. does not contain exactly one resource record.
```

How can I achieve it in route53?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're creating the record with Routing policy value Simple routing. Try using Geolocation or weighted to test it out first.